# Add an 'Agree to terms and conditions' checkbox to a shopify theme called blockshop

Tags: shopify

I need to add Cart - Add an 'Agree to terms and conditions' checkbox to a shopify theme called blockshop

[image]

I'm using Blockshop theme in my Shopify website and would like to add the 'Terms and Conditions checkbox' to it. Will this cause any problem?